# Разработать алгоритм и программу, что решает задачу

Tags: c

Разработать алгоритм и программу, что решает задачу. Есть число Х с плавающей запятой. Рассчитать массив Х[n] так, что

[image]

Как это решить без использования функции пов?

Comment: А оформить вопрос по правилам?

Comment: Приветствую! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу**

Comment: Это даже учебным заданием назвать нельзя. Это какой-то огрызок непонятного текста, не содержащего ни внятного вопроса, ни учебного задания.

Comment: Написал [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1221970/267338) без использования возведения в степень.

Answer (score 2):

Можно заметить что каждый следующий элемент массива отличается от предыдущего всего лишь одним последним дополнительным слагаемым, остальные слагаемыме совпадают. Также можно заметить, что каждое следующее слагаемое содержит в себе степень X на два больше чем предыдущее и противоположный знак. В итоге итеративно можно хранить текущую степень, а следующую вычислять просто домножением на `-1 * X * X`.

В итоге можно написать такую простейшую C-программу вычисления этих элементов массива без использования функции возведения в степень:

[Попробовать программу онлайн!](https://tio.run/##ZU7JCoMwFLz7FUNLwb1Jl5PaHykerEsb0FhcQBC/3b4YbJHOJWHebKmXlol8zvNeyLTssxxh22Wi9l83wxCyQ5UIaVoYDRBy2VcYIRGBM0zBQmZ1/yhzDESefX7h1y2d3GWsGfqymFTDRlD1ZUekN7hoKT0C0@eibmCqBUK1BfSEkAEcR6xrFBa3TXYOmybYa7iCinMiLTnCPNFVwAG3fhKaJNQkkmpy@u9mm@6v9d2QoDB3hwI7VwdR8DTPHw)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    enum { n = 10 };
    double x = 3.1415;
    double xa[n];
    xa[0] = x;
    double mult = -x, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        mult *= -1 * x * x;
        sum += mult / (2 * i + 1);
        xa[i] = sum;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%f ", xa[i]);
}
```

Вывод:

```
3.141500 10.334511 -50.860401 380.520992 -2930.722114 23806.422154 -199467.746188 1710230.290999 -14919345.373513 131922764.526441
```